# How to make load balancer for log collecting?

Tags: linux, logging, load-balancing

I'm trying to make load balancer for my log collecting servers, but my researches gives me all for web servers, with Nginx,Apache,HAProxy.. But i have not web servers it's only for like ip forwarding..

What's your opinion / ideas for solution?

Thx.

Comment: HAProxy can forward traffic to any ports on a given cluster of servers and so is definitely an option.